# How to Access different Properties or attributes of Selected Object among an Array of Objects in prepareForSegue method

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, segue

First of all my issue is serious & not for those who are only willing to assign negative Feedback or just here for editing & get reward purpose.

my problem is complicated to convey, yet I am trying my best to convey complete issue.
Actually I've two table views and two Json files in backend, and an AVPlayerViewController. First of alll firstTableViewController shows first json file which contains Following Json Data

```
    [{
    "id": "0",
    "name": "Religion"
}, {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "News"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Sport"
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Doc"
}, {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Kids"
}, {
    "id": "5",
    "name": "Music"
}, {
    "id": "6",
    "name": "Movie"
}, {
    "id": "7",
    "name": "Entr"
}, {
    "id": "8",
    "name": "Cooking"
}, {
    "id": "9",
    "name": "All"
}]
```

In SecondViewController which extracting [second Json file](https://creativestudy.000webhostapp.com/webservices/test.json) containing different links along-with categories mentioned in above first json file.
both of the Json File's data retrieved successfully in my app.

When I click in any cell(containing specific Category) of my FirstTableViewController it brings me to the secondTableViewController with `title` property of all  objects containing that specific category(named as `category_name` in second json file) selected category. 
Up to here everything works pretty cool. 
but the problem arising when I used to click at any title it should bring me to AVPlayerViewController and to play relevant livestream link. but it giving me following error,

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[**NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2097174 beyond bounds
>   [0 .. 32]'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104b0234b __exceptionPreprocess + 171  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x000000010456321e objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x0000000104a33f1b -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 203     3   AlbTVRadio 
>   0x00000001022bcae1 -[Second prepareForSegue:sender:] + 321    4   UIKit 
>   0x0000000102bbef5f -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate
>   _performWithDestinationViewController:sender:] + 353  5   UIKit                               0x0000000102bbedcd -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 82  6
>
>   UIKit                               0x0000000102bbf08f
>   -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 156   7   UIKit                               0x000000010253b52a -[UITableView
>   _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1769     8   UIKit                               0x000000010253b78d
>   -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 330   9   UIKit                               0x00000001023f12eb
>   _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 320     10  UIKit                               0x00000001023ddf6f _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 566   11 
>   UIKit                               0x000000010240f3da
>   _afterCACommitHandler + 176   12  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104aa6e17
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 23    13  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104aa6d87
>   __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391  14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104a8bb9e __CFRunLoopRun + 1198    15  CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000104a8b494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420     16  GraphicsServices
>   0x0000000106784a6f GSEventRunModal + 161  17  UIKit
>   0x00000001023e4964 UIApplicationMain + 159    18  AlbTVRadio
>   0x00000001022cd65f main + 111     19  libdyld.dylib
>   0x000000010a00968d start + 1  20  ???
>   0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

I think problem is in the  ***segue*** code, that is not picking accurate `ChannelObject` or `Object.livestream`

Here is my code for the second viewController. which containing that second json file. so please correct this code if possible.

```
#import "Second.h"
#import "Channel.h"
#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"
#import "Type.h"
#define getDataUrl @"https://creativestudy.000webhostapp.com/webservices/test.json"

@interface Second ()

@end

@implementation Second
@synthesize tvArray,currentObject;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self retrieveData];



    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return tvArray.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cells" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Channel * ChannelObject;
    ChannelObject = [tvArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = ChannelObject.channelTitle;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = ChannelObject.channelLivestream;
     cell.detailTextLabel.hidden = YES;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:ChannelObject.channelImage];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    UIImage *placeholderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"];
    __weak UITableViewCell *weakCell = cell;
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:placeholderImage success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
        weakCell.imageView.image = image;
        [weakCell setNeedsLayout];
    } failure:nil];



    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
-(void) getType:(id)typeObject{

    currentObject = typeObject;

}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/


// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"playVideo"]) {

            AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

             NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
             Channel * ChannelObject;
            ChannelObject = [self.tvArray objectAtIndex:(int)indexPath];
             NSURL *liveUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:ChannelObject.channelLivestream];
             playerViewController.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:liveUrl];
        [playerViewController.player play];

             }

}


-(void) retrieveData{
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataUrl];
    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    tvArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i ++)
    {
        NSDictionary *aCategoryJSON = [jsonArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *cId = [aCategoryJSON objectForKey:@"id"];
        NSString *cTitle = [aCategoryJSON objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSString *cCategory = [aCategoryJSON objectForKey:@"category_name"];
        NSString *cImage = [aCategoryJSON objectForKey:@"image"];
        NSString *cLivestream = [aCategoryJSON objectForKey:@"livestream"];
        NSString *cWebsite = [aCategoryJSON objectForKey:@"Website"];
        if (cCategory == currentObject.typeName){
        [tvArray addObject:[[Channel alloc] initWithChannelId:cId andChannelTitle:cTitle andChannelCategory:cCategory andChannelImage:cImage andChannelLivestream:cLivestream andChannelWebsite:cWebsite]];
        }
        else if ([currentObject.typeName isEqualToString: @"All"]){
        [tvArray addObject:[[Channel alloc] initWithChannelId:cId andChannelTitle:cTitle andChannelCategory:cCategory andChannelImage:cImage andChannelLivestream:cLivestream andChannelWebsite:cWebsite]];
        }

    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

@end
```

Comment: Please post the complete exception call stack (the one with _Terminating app due to uncaught exception_...)

Comment: You're facing the problem due to the array you're using because it is exceeding its maximum limit. maybe you should check your retrieveData function.

Comment: Place an exception breakpoint and see on which line the exception is taking place. @Hina

Comment: `ChannelObject = [self.tvArray objectAtIndex:(int)indexPath];` This is the exact line of code (my guess) where it is crashing. There are only 32 items and your index in beyond 32.

Comment: yes, you are right @Sachin_Vas, but I don't know how to figure out this issue. because I've a single json file containing all the lists, for second viewcontroller if you notice, & in `retrieveData` Method I have to filter only selected categories and to post in UITableview. hence if there are only 32 items with relevant category. and I click at second item it thorws error because in actual Json file it is not at that index or it'll be something like that which is out of my mind.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen actual problem is in the segue. For your convenient if you notice `retireveData` method you'll also come to know that how I am extracting data from json file, and also to please notice in UITableViewCell method. where I am posting data with following lines `Channel * ChannelObject;
    ChannelObject = [tvArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = ChannelObject.channelTitle;` and now finally notice segue method where actual issue arising in these two lines ` Channel * ChannelObject;
            ChannelObject = [self.tvArray objectAtIndex:(int)indexPath]; `

Comment: @dreamBegin yes you are right, my `tvArray` contains only that mentioned items because I've filtered only selected categories from Json file, & now when I click at any of the title for playing its relevant video it is giving me error because there are specific items in the array which I retrieved from json but I don't know why my code going to original Json for playing any item. its really complicated to convey...

Comment: you need to debug that code again , include some breakpoint in you code and i'm sure you'll find out the error soon.make sure you examine all the values.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen Please check complete exception call in highlighted area

Comment: @dreamBegin Ok I am trying to make some breakpoints & to debug my code again, lets see what happening this time...

Comment: @AndreasOetjen , sorry could not be succeeded in problem configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
 ChannelObject = [self.tvArray objectAtIndex:(int)indexPath];
```

You have cast an object (an instance of `NSIndexPath`) to an int, and Objective-C has let you since it is based on C, even though that makes no sense.

`indexPath` is a pointer to an object in memory, so when you cast it to `int` you get a memory address interpreted as an integer, which is why you see an attempt to access element 2097174 in your array.  Presumably you added the cast to `int` because the compiler was telling you that you can't use an indexPath in that function.

What you need to do is use `indexPath.row` to get the row integer from the `NSIndexPath` instance.  You can also use the more modern array access syntax and a lower case letter to start a variable (upper case letters are for classes):

```
Channel *channelObject = self.tvArray[indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Let me try & test to what you said & suggested in your answer, 
But if you try to notice, I've already pointed to the selected index's row in              `NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];` line which is right above two lines of line  `ChannelObject = [self.tvArray objectAtIndex:(int)indexPath];`  which is is in this discussion.  But yet, thanks for your suggestion, let me try that, hopefully comeback with the result whatever it should be. . .

Comment: `indexPathForSelectedRow` gives you an `NSIndexPath` as its name suggests.  You then need to use `indexPath.row` to get the selected row.  You are trying to use the `indexPath` directly as an array index, which is why you had to cast it to an int and why you get an array bounds exception with a crazy index

Comment: @Paul11 , Pretty cool, it works like a pro... Thumbs up for your solution.